# Passing value with Razor Engine one a SPA

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, single-page-application, route-provider

Have a SPA and I want to open a page to pass a value to a controller.

Route Controller:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/showdata/:id',
                        {
                        templateUrl: 'Data/ShowData',
                        });
```

View

```
    <tbody>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><a href="showdata/@item.id">100</a></td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ShowGraphs(int id){
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id " + id);
    }
```

This is not working...

And this is not working too

```
<td style="text-align:center"><a  href='@Url.Action("showdata")'>100</a></td>

<td>@Html.ActionLink(@item.id, "showdata", new { id= @item.id})</td>
```

Only this works

```
<td style="text-align:center"><a href="showdata">100</a></td>
```

when Route Controller is

```
 $routeProvider.when('/showdata',
                        {
                        templateUrl: 'Data/ShowData',
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

View

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center"><a href="showdata/@item.id">100</a></td>
        </tr>
    }

</tbody>
```

Route

```
$routeProvider.when('/showdata/:id',
                        {
                         templateUrl: function (params) { return '/Data/ShowData?id=' + params.id; },
                        });
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ShowGraphs(){
       Uri uri = new Uri(this.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
       //parse for query
    }
```